# Why does {settings.split} return "" instead of the expected array value shown by <f:debug>?

Tags: typo3, settings, flux, fluid, typo3-10.x

I am using flux to create a two column content element (based on contents from the former fluid-bootstrap-theme, since I was using it back then).
When using the variable `settings.split` in the content template it shows value `a` in the `<f.debug>` dump. However using `{settings.split}` returns nothing when rendering in the browser.
I don't understand why it does not return `a`.

A variable titled `adsettings.split` returns `a` as expected.

Can you give me some advice?
Thank you very much!

Code Example in Templates/Content/TwoColumn.html:

```xml
    <f:layout name="Default" />
    
    <f:section name="Configuration">
        <f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>
        <flux:form id="andre">
            <flux:form.sheet name="colSettings">
                <flux:field.select name="adsettings.split"
                                   items="a,b,c,d"
                                   default="a"
                                   requestUpdate="1">
                </flux:field.select>
                <flux:field.select name="settings.split"
                                   items="a,b,c,d"
                                   default="a"
                                   requestUpdate="1">
                </flux:field.select>
            </flux:form.sheet>
        </flux:form>
    </f:section>
    
    <f:section name="Preview">
    {settings.split}
        {split}
    </f:section>
    
    <f:section name="Main">
        ADSettings: {adsettings.split}
        Settings: {settings.split}
    </f:section>
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of Output]

Versions:

- Typo3 10.4.9
- Flux 9.4.2
- Vhs 6.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you renamed the field before after Saving and editing it in the Backend? The code is correct i tested it in my FCE.

Solution:
Delete the Element and create a new One,  then it will work.

Comment: Notice:  The using of:  <flux:form.XXX is depracted

you need to use the flux form field like that:
`<flux:field type="select" name="imageStyle" config="{ renderType: 'selectSingle',

items: {

 0:{0:'Standard',1:'small'},

 1:{0:'großes Bild',1:'big'}

 },

 default: 'small'

 }" label="Darstellung"/>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your answer and include everything there - code is much harder to read in comments. Also, please try to phrase answers assertively, otherwise there is a risk that they may be deleted if the are mistaken for a question.

Comment: Thanks, creating a new one was not sufficient. It was the interaction with the already defined settings array in TypoScript, see my other comment.

Thanks for pointing out the deprecation. I would not have found that without a hint. (It's in the release notes of flux, I think it was v. 9.3.)

Answer (score 0):

Each section has it's own context and defined variables. Normaly only those you provide with an `arguments` parameter.

If you put a `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>` in your section you will see different (none) variables.

---

If you want variables in your section you need arguments.

either you transmit only single parameters like:
`<f:render section="Main" arguments="{par1:'string, par2:fluidVar}" />`

or you transmit all available fluid variables with:
`<f:render section="Main" arguments="{_all}" />`

Comment: Thank you very much. In my example I had set a array plugin.tx_ExtensionName.settings in TypoScript setup.txt, which was then superposition with the settings.split from the template. The Main-Section only saw the array from TypoScript and not the one from the Configuration section.